# Bootstrap progress bar colour change according to width value dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, progress-bar

I have created a progress bar. Value is being fetched from database. Now i want to categorize the colour of progress bar like if width value is below 50 so progress bar colour is red. If value is above 50 and below 90 colour is blue if value is 100 then colour is green.

progress bar is display in table cell. and values are fetched from database

```html
 
                                        <tr class="success">
                                            <td><?php echo "$row->ID"; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo "$row->name"; ?></td>
           <td><div class="progress" style = "height:24px;width:200px">
                     
      <div class="progress-bar" id = "newprogress" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="<?php echo "$row->Percentage"; ?>" style = "width :<?php echo "$row->Percentage"; ?>%";>
<?php echo "$row->Percentage" ?>%
       
      </div>
      </div>
   <td>
```

as i have tried one of the solution here

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var bar = parseInt($("#newprogress").width());

  if (bar >= 90) {
    $("#newprogress").removeClass("bckColor").addClass("bar-success");
  }
  else if (bar >= 50 && bar < 90) {
    $("#newprogress").removeClass("bar-success").addClass("bckColor");
  }
  
});
```

Comment: instead of .css('width') use width() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you selected the wrong element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var bars = $('.progress-bar');
  for (i = 0; i < bars.length; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    var progress = $(bars[i]).attr('aria-valuenow');
    $(bars[i]).width(progress + '%');
    if (progress >= "90") {
      $(bars[i]).addClass("bar-success");
    } else if (progress >= "50" && progress < "90") {
      $(bars[i]).addClass("bar-warning");
    } else {
      $(bars[i]).addClass("bar-error");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.progress {
  width: 200px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.progress-bar {
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 24px;
  display: block;
}

.bar-warning {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.bar-success {
  background-color: green;
}

.bar-error {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress" style="heigt:24px;width:200px">
  <div class="progress-bar" name="progress" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90"></div>
</div>

<div class="progress" style="heigt:24px;width:200px">
  <div class="progress-bar" name="progress" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="30"></div>
</div>

<div class="progress" style="heigt:24px;width:200px">
  <div class="progress-bar" name="progress" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="50"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry but it doesnot work. and i retreived progress width value from database

Comment: I adjusted the code & it should work with your `aria-valuenow` attribute & also list of elements

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var bar = parseInt($('.progress').width());

    if (bar >= 90){


        $(".progress").removeClass("bckColor").addClass("success");
        }
    else if (bar >= 50){

        $(".progress").removeClass("success").addClass("bckColor");
        }
});



.bckColor {
    background-color: blue !important;
}

.success {
    background-color: green !important;
}
```

Comment: it does not work. it gives green colour to every bar

Comment: your width in the pixel so try with 10 widths or less width or you can convert width into the percentage

Comment: sorry i do not get your point. progress width value is fetched from database.

Answer (score 0):

**Use the Below code I have named sample.php**
Here the value will be collected from the another file data.php and changes the color according to the condition provided

Languages Used: HTML,PHP, JS

sample.php

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title></title>
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
                        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                        <?php require_once('data.php'); ?>
                        <script>
                var myVar = setInterval(inter, 1000);
                function inter() {

                        document.getElementById("boot").style.width = 
                            <?php echo $x; ?>+"%";
                        document.getElementById("boot").innerHTML = 
                            <?php echo $x; ?>+"%";
                            if (
                            <?php echo $x; ?>< 90)
                            {
                                document.getElementById("boot").className = "progress-bar progress-bar-danger";
                            }
                             else
                             {
                                document.getElementById("boot").className = "progress-bar progress-bar-success";
                                }
            }


                        </script>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <table>
                            <td>
                                <div class="progress" style = "height:24px;width:200px">
                                    <div name="progress" role="progressbar" id="boot" aria-valuenow="
                                        <?php echo'$row->Percentage';?>" >
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </table>
                    </body>
                </html>
```

**Here is data.php**

Results:

---

[image: When its 90% or above]

[image: When its <80%]

Answer (score 0):

I realise you were asking for a JavaScript solution, but this can be achieved (somewhat) in PHP.

You are already working with variables in the PHP script to set values for your HTML output, so why not do the same for the colour of your progress bar?

This example uses the default Bootstrap colours, but you can substitute others if you require:

```
    // Value retrieved from the database. This can be a percentage (which may be easier
    // to work with or just use the raw value depending on your needs)
    $valueFromDatabase = 9;

    // This will give us a green bar, 9% wide.

    // Use the switch command to set the output colour (using the Bootstrap 
    // default colours Primary, Warning, Danger, Success etc. Set these as you need.
    switch ($valueFromDatabase) {

        case ($valueFromDatabase <= 10):
            $bar_colour = "success";
        break;
        case (($valueFromDatabase > 10) && ($valueFromDatabase <= 30)):
            $bar_colour = "warning";
        break;
        case ($valueFromDatabase > 30):
            $bar_colour = "danger";
        break;
    }

    // Now we use $bar_colour to set the colour in the output below.
    // Width set to the value retrieved from the database

    echo "<div class='row'>\n
        <div class='col-md-12'>\n
            <h4>Your Progress Bar</h4>\n
            <div class='progress md-progress pos-rel' style='height:25px'>\n
                <div class='progress-bar progress-bar-$bar_colour progress-bar-striped' style='width:$valueFromDatabase%; height: 25px'>
                    <span style='line-height: 25px'>$valueFromDatabase%</span>
                </div>\n
            </div>\n
        </div>\n
        </div>\n";
```